# Toggling list vs on click

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which displays first 5 items and the  rest is hidden until the user click on "show more" and the "show more" is replaced with "show less".

Is it possible to  do it using toggle instead of on click? .
HTML

```
 <ul id="business-type-div" class="list-group" style="">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="All" autocomplete="on" id="filter-business-type-all" > All</li>

                                <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Auto" id="auto" autocomplete="off"> Auto</li>

                                <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Entertainment" id="entertainment" autocomplete="off"> Entertainment</li>

                                <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Food and Beverage Services" id="restaurant-checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Food and Beverage Services</li>

                                <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Health and Wellness" id="health" autocomplete="off"> Health and Wellness</li>



                                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Rental and Leasing" id="RentalandLeasing" autocomplete="off"> Rental and Leasing</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Retail" id="Retail" autocomplete="off"> Retail</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Services" id="Services" autocomplete="off"> Services</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Social Assistance" id="Social" autocomplete="off"> Social Assistance</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Transportation" id="Transportation" autocomplete="off"> Transportation</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="filter-business-type" value="Warehousing" id="Warehousing" autocomplete="off"> Warehousing </li>


                                    <div class="show-more" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="#">Show More</a><span class="arrow-down"></span>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="show-less" style="display: none;">
                                        <a href="#">Show Less</a><span class="arrow-up"></span>
                                     </div>




                            </ul>
```

JavaScript

```
   /** SHOW MORE  show LESS **/
$('#business-type-div li:gt(4)').hide();
$('.show-more').click(function(e) {
    $('ul li:gt(6)').show();
    $('.show-more').hide();
    $('.show-less').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.show-less').click(function(e) {
    $('#business-type-div li:gt(4)').hide();
    $('.show-more').show();
    $('.show-less').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You can use `$('.show-more, .show-less').toggle()`, if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toggle()` function to switch between hiding and showing elements. In this case, you are looking for the list items ranked 6th and above. Since you're calling this selector multiple times, it's a good practice to store it in a variable.

```
var moreResults = $("#business-type-div li:gt(4)");

moreResults.hide();
$('.show-more a').click(function(e) {
    moreResults.toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text($(this).text() === "Show Less" ? "Show More" : "Show Less");
});
```

Your code also missed a couple list items.

`$('ul li:gt(6)').show();` should have been `$('ul li:gt(4)).show()`. Probably a mistake, but can be prevented by storing the selector in a variable like I explained above.

You also no longer need the `show-less` div, because you can simply change the text of the `show-more` div with jQuery. This also makes for cleaner, drier code.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzmLc6z6/4/

Comment: `$(".show-more").text() ===` will refer to **any** `.show-more` in the document. Be careful. Fix that issue. Use the `$(this)` reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

To start of, you **cannot** use `<div>` element as child of `<ul>` as UL accepts only LI elements.

So you need to find out a new place for your MORE/LESS buttons with an
**improved HTML**:

```js
$("div.group").each(function() { // Handle multiple groups!

  var $UL     = $(this).find(".list-group");
  var $LI     = $UL.find("li");
  var $LIplus = $LI.filter(":gt(3)");
  var $MORE   = $(this).find(".show-more");
  var $LESS   = $(this).find(".show-less");

  $LESS.add( $LIplus ).hide();

  $LESS.add( $MORE ).click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent the browser jump to top
    $LIplus.add( $LESS ).add( $MORE ).toggle(); // Toggle 'em all :D
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <h2>BUSINESS</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show More</a><span class="arrow-down"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="show-less">
    <a href="#">Show Less</a><span class="arrow-up"></span>
  </div>
</div><!-- END OF DIV GRoUP -->

<div class="group">
  <h2>SPORT</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show More</a><span class="arrow-down"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="show-less">
    <a href="#">Show Less</a><span class="arrow-up"></span>
  </div>
</div><!-- END OF DIV GRoUP -->
```

Answer (score 0):

## No.

It is not possible to do it using toggle. You have to use function binding event (click in this example) with action.

I think you want to do something like:

```
/** SHOW - TOGGLE **/
$('#business-type-div li:gt(4)').hide();
$('.show-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children().toggle(); // toggle button
    $(this).closest('.list-group').find('li:gt(4)').toggle(); // toggle list
});
```

with modified HTML:

```
<div class="show-toggle">
    <a href="#">Show More <span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none">Show Less <span class="arrow-up"></span></a>
</div>
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/cknc778f/

//Sidenote: In theory you can do it without any JavaScript - CSS3 only. But should you? No.